# fix textarea height size

Tags: html, css

I hope you can help me, I'm junior in html/css

I have a textarea with **known** height in percentage value **inside** a div of **unknown** height, when I'm trying to write inside this textarea, it's height get changed.

my question is, how to fix textarea height when trying to write inside it by percentage value

I know that I need to fix div height first by specify its height using **px** or **%** in order to make textarea height fix.

I tried these attributes but no luck

```
resize: none;
display:block;
```

Please note that the div height is changeable and it works as container for multiple textarea so that I can't add a specific height for it,

BTW, this issue is happening on all browsers

Please help

Comment: Can you specify `max-height` property?

Comment: When you write inside a `textarea` its height changes? Its the first time I hear about that feature...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

CSS rule `resize: none;` does this job.

You can also set your textarea height in rows count with `rows` attribute.

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
}
textarea.ta10em {
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea rows=3>Some text
Second line
Third line</textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <textarea class="ta10em">Some text
Second line</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @vp_arth, this helped me, I have used em instead of %, it's fixed my problem and kept textarea responsive as well

Answer (score 3):

first of all. make sure there is no style in your **html** conflict with you **css** .

that can cause same problem

- for all textarea :

  ```
  textarea {
   resize: none;
  }
  ```
- or

  ```
  textarea { 
   max-height: 100px;
  }
  ```

change "100" to what ever you want.

or try this in your textarea :

```
<textarea style="resize:none"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks @kakashi, appreciate  your help I checked my html and css but I didn't see any conflict, I tried your solution but the textarea still changes.